# leaflet geojson coordinates to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

```js
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([53.7983587, -1.6191674], 11);
    mymap.createPane('labels');
    mymap.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
    mymap.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    
    var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '©OpenStreetMap, ©CartoDB'
}).addTo(mymap);

var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '©OpenStreetMap, ©CartoDB',
        pane: 'labels'
}).addTo(mymap);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/adam97x/cjavcj1680vgz2sqshn70q5pg/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWRhbTk3eCIsImEiOiJjamF2Y2k1NmswYzhuMnZtazlpNXU2NDExIn0.RifBBI5nelL-4d21mkn7Wg', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
 }).addTo(mymap);
 
  // control that shows state info on hover
 var info = L.control();

 info.onAdd = function (mymap) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
  this.update();
  return this._div;
 };

 info.update = function (props) {
  this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Highlighted Postcode</h4>' +  (props ?
   '<b> Postcode: ' + props.Name
   : 'Hover over a state');
 };

 info.addTo(mymap);
 

function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: 'grey',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    };
}

L.geoJson(statesdata, {style: style}).addTo(mymap);

 function highlightFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;

  layer.setStyle({
   weight: 5,
   opacity: 1,
   color: '#000',
   dashArray: '',
   fillOpacity: 0.7
  });

  if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
   layer.bringToFront();
  }

  info.update(layer.feature.properties);
 }

 var geojson;

 function resetHighlight(e) {
  geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
  info.update();
 }
     function zoomToFeature(e) {
    mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
                var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;
                console.log(coords);
 }
 coords = []; //define an array to store coordinates
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
   mouseover: highlightFeature,
   mouseout: resetHighlight,
   click: zoomToFeature
  });
 }
  
  
 geojson = L.geoJson(statesdata, {
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
 }).addTo(mymap);
 test = [];
geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.Name);

});
```

```css
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
  .info { padding: 6px 8px; font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: white; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 5px; } .info h4 { margin: 0 0 5px; color: #777; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>KML Data</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://project-adam97.c9users.io/asset/bd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>

<div id='map'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to output the geojson file's coordinates into an array upon clicking a sector (post code) of the map so i can flip them to lat,lng instead of lng,lat however I am struggling to do so.

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
                var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;
                console.log(coords);
}
```

I would have though it is something along these lines however I am getting feature is not defined as a result in the console, if anybody has any suggestions please let me know. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1748o3r/2/) it logs to console 241 times. It also printed out when HTML was pasted "as is" getting some warnings, see [that version](https://jsfiddle.net/y1748o3r/).

Comment: Sorry, I updated my original post without saying my new problem, I only want the geojson long lats, to display when a postcode sector is clicked, that's the thing I cannot work out as it keeps saying x is not defined.

Comment: There is no place in your code pasted here that has `x` property, so I am not really sure where is your problem... anyway, is long lat of click point inside `zoomToFeature()` that you want?

Answer (score 0):

To get different details associated with click simply inspect event object passed to your click listener. For example:

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    console.log(e.latlng); // {lat: 53.80551690917758, lng: -1.68365478515625}
    console.log(e.target.feature); // {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
}
```

To see what you can get from that event simply print it out as `console.log(e)` and unfold its subobject to see what you can get from it.